# Is this code a valid alternative to "padding top" for header-banners?

Tags: html, css

I hope someone can give me an answer to that. It's about an apparent alternative to a popular CSS method.

I guess it's well-known that you can use padding-top with background for e.g. header-banners in order to position several elements in the foreground of a header-banner, like for example:

```
.header-banner {
  background: url(../img/background-banner.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-top: 20.83%;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now it's easy to fill the header-banner with other elements additionally to the background-banner without bigger problems - in sharp contrast to simple <img> elements that are hard to position in a header-banner along with other elements.
Downside is: You need to calculate the padding-top all over again if the image sizes change, e.g. from 250x1200 (padding-top: 20.83%;) to 300x1100 (padding-top: 27.27%;).

It seems that the padding-top is a very popular solution. My question:
Why the following code is not used?

```
HTML:
    <header class="headerBanner">
      <img src="src/img/background.jpg" alt="banner">
      <p>Content in the foreground of banner</p>
    </header>

CSS:
    .headerBanner {
        position: relative;
    }

    .headerBanner > img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .headerBanner > p {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

This way, we don't need to bother about the image size, and we don't need to calculate "padding-top". Are there any disadvantages I don't see with the second solution? Or are these simply two ways that can be used with the same outcome? In this case, why padding-top is even used because it requires more calculation in case the image size changes?

---

I hope I formulated my question clear enough. Please tell me if I need to change / add something in order to make it more understandable.

Comment: You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header check this out. your approach (change p to h1) is the "classic" one...

Comment: You are asking which version of the wheel is better.  In my experience it's the version that makes your project work. But I tend toward simple solutions.  I try to write code and markup so that it's self explanatory.

Comment: Two different approaches that I would not compare. Padding-top with a percentage value is based on the width so you get an aspect ratio box. An img element inside your header will not provide an aspect ratio box, at various screen sizes the image will not fill the container always.

Comment: Hi together, that answered my question pretty well, thanks a lot!